# Puppet beaker docker acceptance dnsmasq

Tags: debian, dnsmasq, puppet

I am trying to migrate code from puppet 3 to puppet 5 with beaker and acceptance tests.

The following output is given:

> ```
>     journalctl log for dnsmasq:
>     -- Logs begin at Thu 2018-11-29 17:11:40 UTC, end at Thu 2018-11-29 17:14:55 UTC. --
>     Nov 29 17:13:51 debian-stretch systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
>     Nov 29 17:13:51 debian-stretch dnsmasq[10452]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
>     Nov 29 17:13:52 debian-stretch systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Control process exited, code=dumped status=11
>     Nov 29 17:13:52 debian-stretch systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
>     Nov 29 17:13:52 debian-stretch systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Unit entered failed state.
>     Nov 29 17:13:52 debian-stretch systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
>     Nov 29 17:14:55 debian-stretch systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
> ```

How do I go about debugging this? I am not very knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could actually enter the container by adding a sleep task to it and then removed files and trying to start dnsmasq service. After that I figured out which file dnsmasq was complaining about. Long story short: the auth-zone had a comma after which there should have been the subnet, but it was empty instead, because the .erb template didn't get the subnet variable scoped properly.